# How to reduce code's margin (=number of spaces) using Regex?

Tags: regex, character-replacement

Recently, on `Notepad++`, I want to reduce number of spaces at begin of lines.

I searched a `Regular Expression`, but I don't find any.

On a array(=tab) of `Notepad++`, I have following lines

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>ligne normale</p>
        <p>ligne      with    2 spaces  </p>
```

and I want to reduce (= divide by 2 number of spaces) only spaces before '<' character on all lines.

Waiting result is following

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p>ligne normale</p>
    <p>ligne      with    2 spaces  </p>
```

I tried following `Regex` and string replacement

Search: `\s{2}(?<=^\s*)`
Replace:    (= one space)

but `Notepad++` refuses this `Regex` !

I have then tested the same `Regex` on a C++ program that is using PCRE version 7.8.
It indicates that look-behind can only contain fix length string !

Is there a Regex that can do the job ?

PS: the following Regex that use a look-ahead to the job ... partially !

```
\s{2}(?=(\s{2})*<)
```

The last 2 spaces in last line, just before last

are not in the margine and are removed while they must be kept !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried it on Notepad++, but this only uses very basic regular expression features in order to halve the number of start-of-line spaces:

```
Find what:      ^(\s+)\1
Replace with:   $1
```

Comment: thanks. I don't think to repeat part of searching string in search pattern and to reuse it in replace string ! 
I have tested on Notepad++ and this works perfectly.